# SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault is this a list or a single value on the OS level

Tags: .net, security, tls1.2

With `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` set to `SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault` does it assume that at the OS level it's a single value (e.g. enforcing TLS 1.2) or can it be a list (e.g. allowing both TLS 1.1 and 1.2).

Where is this configured at the OS level?

Is there a way to get the list in a .NET application?